# How is a dominant rational map well-defined?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, zariski-topology

I am slightly confused by the definition of a dominant rational map in Hartshorne, specifically because of a comment he makes about the equivalence relation. In Chapter 1.4, he defines a rational map in the usual way. That is, given a variety $X$ with open sets $U$ and $V$, a rational map is an equivalence class of pairs $\left(U, \phi_{U} \right)$ where two pairs $\left(U, \phi_{U} \right)$ and $\left(V, \phi_{V} \right)$ are equivalent if $\phi_{U}$ and $\phi_{V}$ agree on the intersection $U \cap V$. He then defines a dominant rational map as a rational map where for some (and hence every) such pair, the image of $\phi_{U}$ is dense in $Y$.

My issue here is with the "and hence every" part. Why is it that becase the image of $\phi_{U}$ is dense in $Y$ and $\phi_{U}$ and $\phi_{V}$ agree on $U \cap V$, then the image of $\phi_{V}$ must also be dense in $Y$? My intuition tells me that this has something to do with the fact that the variety $X$ is irreducible, but I still can't see it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that if $\phi_U$ is dominant, then $\phi_{U\cap V}$ will also be dominant for $U\cap V \neq \emptyset$. Note that
$$
  \phi_{U\cap V}(U\cap V) = \phi_U(U\cap V).
$$
Now, suppose for a contradiction that there is some nonempty open set $W\subset Y$ such that $W\cap \phi_{U\cap V}(U\cap V) = \emptyset$. By the above equality, $W\cap \phi_U(U\cap V) = \emptyset$. But, we have that
$$
  \phi_U(\phi_U^{-1}(W) \cap U\cap V) = W \cap \phi_U(U\cap V) = \emptyset,
$$
so $\phi_U^{-1}(W)\cap U\cap V = \emptyset$.
But because $\phi_U$ is dominant, $W\cap \phi_U(U)\neq \emptyset$, so the preimage $\phi_U^{-1}(W)$ is nonempty and open in $X$. Thus, it must intersect $U\cap V$ because $X$ is irreducible. A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you Andrew this is much appreciated. While I am comfortable with this proof though, by the wording of Hartshorne it seems like this is meant to be some self evident fact. Is Hartshorne just known for glossing over those things or was I meant to see a proof like this instantly?

Comment: Indeed. I have found Hartshorne to be very brief in places. I recommend you supplement it with other sources, such as Vakil's notes.

Comment: @Luke This is mostly how Hartshorne operates. In his defense, he needs to cover a lot of ground and this was not a hard thing to check. In my view other books tend to sacrifice too much in the way of brevity, geometry, or completeness; there are always trade-offs. Happily, you can read more than one book.